# Looping through an array with CSS rules, and applying them to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want users to be able to input CSS input, and have that CSS applied to the last selected element(selected by the "rangeselector" variable). The code selects the right element, but only the first CSS-rule is applied.

ex: "background: blue; color:red;" only applies the background.

The function runs through the array correctly.

```
function customCss(){
  css = $("input.css").val();
  if(css.length < 10){
        alert("Insert valid CSS");
  }else{

        cssArray = css.split(";");
        counter = 0;
        cssArray.forEach(function(){
              var ruleSplit = cssArray[counter].split(":");
              target = $("[content_child=" + rangeselector + "]");
              target.css(ruleSplit[0] , ruleSplit[1]);
              counter = counter + 1;
        });
  }
}
```

If you know the problem, or have a better way of achieving the same goal, i would gladly hear you suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: In what format the user input the CSS?

Comment: How you would write it in a document

Comment: Where is rangeselector defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried stripping the elements before you set them? What's probably happening is that it's trying to set something like "color " instead of "color"

```
function customCss(){
  css = $("input.css").val();
  if(css.length < 10){
        alert("Insert valid CSS");
  }else{

        cssArray = css.split(";");
        counter = 0;
        cssArray.forEach(function(){
              var ruleSplit = cssArray[counter].split(":");
              target = $("[content_child=" + rangeselector + "]");
              target.css(ruleSplit[0].trim() , ruleSplit[1].trim());
              counter = counter + 1;
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd also consider refactoring the code like nanndoj suggested, you have no need for a counter.

Answer (score 1):

By using [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you already have the index and the reference to Array. You don't need use a counter

```
    cssArray = css.split(";");
    // counter = 0;
    cssArray.forEach(function(obj, key, array){
          var ruleSplit = obj.split(":");
          target = $("[content_child=" + rangeselector + "]");
          target.css(ruleSplit[0] , ruleSplit[1]);
          // counter = counter + 1;
    });
```